# Expo: Default browser for expo start

Tags: command-line-interface, expo, default-browser

Is there a way to change the browser in which the Expo interface (`http://localhost:19002/`) opens after `expo start`?

My default browser is Firefox, which I use for my private life. My work and coding browser is Chrome. Is there a way to tell Expo to use Chrome by default?

Answer (score 3):

`expo start` looks at the `BROWSER` environment variable before using the default browser so you can switch to Chrome just by setting that env var before calling `expo start`

As a raw command it looks like this for Windows:

```
set BROWSER=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe && expo start
```

For my workflow I have just updated `package.json` so the `yarn run start` script does it for me:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set BROWSER=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe && expo start",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Most easy way is to copy your "http://localhost:19002/" and paste it in browser
where you want to open your project

Comment: That's not an answer. The question is not how to open a link in a browser but how to set the default browser for `expo start`.